# EC2 Instance Python Script Execution Slows to a Crawl in Middle of Execution

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

My local environment is Windows 7 with Anaconda Python 2.7.

I also have a local Windows 10 environment with Anaconda Python 2.7.

I have a highly iterative script developed in Spyder IDE.

The script performs a lot of separate (not embedded) iterations.

The script executes perfectly in my local environments.

I have created several separate compute-intensive images on Amazon EC2 using various versions of Window Server and Anaconda Python 2.7 and Spyder.

Regardless of the instance (which vary in terms of memory and cpu), my script executes up to a particular loop and then slows to a crawl.

Can anyone help source the issue?

Comment: Is your EC2 instanceType a `t2.xyz` type?  If so, they utilize a CPU credit system which you may be consuming, which will cause CPU throttling.

Comment: no. They are compute intensive (e.g., `c4.8xlarge`)